# Как выделить память указателю, если не известно количество элементов в структуре?

Tags: c

У меня есть структура, пример:

```
typedef struct main
{
  st0_t *st0;

  char *name;
  char *pass;
  char *host;
}main_t;
```

Мне нужно создать указатель на структуру main, но в действительности точное количество элементов в структуре не известно, то есть их может быть, как в примере - 4, так и более 4х. Собственно вопрос, как выделить память указателю использую calloc при условие, что количество элементов не известно?

Comment: Прочитайте про списки

Comment: Точное количество полей структуры всегда известно уже в момент компиляции.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
main_t *pointer = calloc(1, sizeof(main_t);
```

Для одного указателя. И не важно, сколько внутри элементов.